# Clear string buffer when buffer is full. What pattern is this?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the name of a particular pattern.

What I'd like to do is have a string buffer that can hold x number of elements. When all the elements are filled the contents of the buffer will be written/appended to a file and the buffer will clear.

What pattern is this as I would like to implement this in my own application. I'm using C++. I don't want a complete solution, just some advice on how this works.

Comment: "Flush buffer when full" is considered a pattern now? What's next, the "increase integer to count stuff"-pattern?

Comment: You can simply use an `ofstream` and it will internally buffer your output and write it when either the buffer's full or you flush (by streaming the `flush` or `endl` iomanipulators or calling the `ostream::flush` member function).  Look at the [`setbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf) function if you want to customise the buffer size.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I didn't know if it was or wasn't a pattern. I see it in many applications such as sockets. I assumed there was some pattern or convention behind it. I'm still learning C++, coming from a high level language. Still lots to learn. I have noticed in C++ you tend to have to implement things yourself, something I've not really had to deal with much in higher level languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is simply called `buffer`; a very classical old pattern indeed.
And it can be used with the classical operations on it. There are no specific designations for that: read, write, flush and optionally a variable for the buffer's state.

P.S.: Will opt to delete/close your question, because it is not a programming related question. There are other forums here on SE: Algorithms, Computer Science, Unix/Linux, etc.